# mcrypt_decrypt function stuck in eternal loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, mcrypt

I'm working through a decryption function and have hit a wall. I'm not very experienced with Actionscript but when I run this function it goes on an infinite loop.

```
private function mcrypt_decrypt(param1:Array, param2:Number,param3:Number): Array {
 var _loc4_:* = -9.57401312E8;
 while(_loc4_)
 {
    var param3:Number = param3 - ((param2 << 4 ^ param2 >>> 5) + param2 ^ _loc4_ + param1[_loc4_ >>> 11 & 3]);
    _loc4_ = _loc4_ - -1640531527;
    var param2:Number = param2 - ((param3 << 4 ^ param3 >>> 5) + param3 ^ _loc4_ + param1[_loc4_ & 3]);
 }
 return [param2,param3];
}
```

From testing I see that *loc4* starts as -9.57401312E8 and then as iteration continues -1640531527 is removed each time, but in what case would this satisfy the while condition? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure about the value after each iteration? I'm a little rusty these days at using Actionscript since it has been years, but this line _loc4_ = _loc4_ - -1640531527; looks to me like it's adding 1640531527 instead of subtracting... whenever I see a double minus sign I see a plus sign.

Comment: From what I can see, the output after one iteration is 683130215.0, then after another its 2323661742.0 then after a 3rd it is 3964193269.0. So you'd be right about it adding but that only complicates it further as to when the while condition would be satisfied...

Comment: the while would exit only when _loc4_ is truly equal to 0 which will be never in your case.

Comment: I would assume this is receiving data from a php service as mcrypt_decrypt function name matches the mcrypt module.   -1640531527 is hexadecimal 0x9e3779b9 and is used in many hash functions from boost, tea, etc.. hash combine routines. You could use as3Crypto functions to replace/fix this routine.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is stuck in an eternal loop because of this:

_loc4_ = _loc4_ - -1640531527;

A double minus sign is the same as a plus sign. Since the value is never zero, the evaluation in your loop always returns true.

Comment: I see, however the confusing part about it is that this is a working method within a *.swf I decompiled. Maybe its an issue with the decompiler?

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, that is probably what happened. Where you have var _loc4_:* = -9.57401312E8; the de-compiler probably misinterpreted the number. Since this is a crypto function, I would not be surprised at all if some kind of obfuscation was at work here.

Comment: Why are you having to de-compile this anyway? Can't you just open up the project and work with it from the original source code?

Comment: Calm down, i'm just curious on its functionality. I'm not stealing code from anyone. The reason I posted here is because the algorithm it's following is the TEA (Tiny Encryption Algorithm) but the sum and delta seem to be exclusive which is why I was curious. The method itself isn't anything that isn't public

Comment: From where? How did you jump to these conclusions, I'm asking a simple actionscript question on a public encryption method

Comment: mcrypt decrypt is a std hash routine that is available in just about all languages... source is available to it to many languages, nothing funky about it